# consider the mapping $w = \sin(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that line segment $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{\pi}{2}, y=0$, and the vertical line $x = a$, where $|a| < \frac{\pi}{2}$, are mapped onto orthogonal curves.

What is meant by orthogonal curves when it comes to complex plane?

Answer (score 0):

Two curves are orthogonal when they cross each other at right angles. For instance, each line passing through the origin is orthogonal to each circle centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic functions preserve angles, and therefore it's enough to show that $y=0$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x=a$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<a<\frac{\pi}{2}$ cross in a right angle. But this is obvious, the former lies on the $x$-axis and the latter lies on the $y$-axis. They cross because of the conditions on $a$.

Because $w(z)=\sin(z)$ is analytic, the curves mapped by $w(z)$ are orthogonal.